# I have a multiple checkbox but i want save only single checkbox value in activity

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
   {
      private LayoutInflater mInflater;
      private Context mContext;
      public ImageAdapter(Context context) 
      {
           mContext = context;
      }
      public int getCount() 
      {
           return count;
      }
      public Object getItem(int position) 
      {
           return position;
      }
      public long getItemId(int position) 
      {
           return position;
      }
      public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
      {
           final ViewHolder holder;
           if (convertView == null) 
           {    
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.state_info, null); 

                holder = new ViewHolder();                                      
                holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);                                              
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox); 

                convertView.setTag(holder);

           } 
           else 
           {    
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
           }          

           convertView.setTag(holder);

           //holder.checkbox.setId(position);
           holder.textview.setId(position);

           holder.checkbox.setId(position);
           holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) 
               {           
                   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                   {       
                       if (v.getId() == i) 
                       {   
                           thumbnailsselection[i] = true;
                           Log.v("check", ""+position);

                       }   
                       else 
                       {   
                           thumbnailsselection[i] = false;
                       }   
                   }
                   notifyDataSetChanged();
               }
           });

           if (thumbnailsselection[position]) 
           {
               holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
           } 
           else 
           {
               holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
           }

           holder.textview.setText(items.get(position).getName());

           holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
           holder.id = position;
           return convertView;

      }          

 }
```

Comment: Have a look at sharedPreferences and save a bool value in this, read it in onResume and set the checkstate of your checkbox

Comment: What is your question? Please say something more than just the code.

Comment: what is the question here? save checkbox value where? in SQLite, on server, in file, in activity.. ???

Comment: @user2294439 dude nobody's gonna eat u ,pls explain what r u really up to

Comment: how to save checkbox value in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement on check chnge listener in your class when the check box is check Add the value in string or any where you desire on uncheck simply remove that And when you come back to your view You want to check first the value if match then check the check box of that location This may helps you

OnCheckedChangeListener Check_Boxes_Listener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {

        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) buttonView;

        if (cb.isChecked() == true) {

            if (Maximum_Selected_Check_Boxes < 16) {
                Maximum_Selected_Check_Boxes++;
                HashMap<String, String> Index = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Index.put("Index", cb.getTag().toString());
                selectCBs.add(Index);

            }

            else

            if (Maximum_Selected_Check_Boxes >= 16) {

                Toast.makeText(Check_Boxes,
                        "You have selected the Maximum Items",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cb.setChecked(false);

            }

        } else if (cb.isChecked() == false) {
            Maximum_Selected_Check_Boxes--;

            String Uncheck = cb.getTag().toString();

            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < selectCBs.size(); i++) {
                if (Uncheck.equalsIgnoreCase(selectCBs.get(i).get("Index")
                        .toString())) {
                    j = i;
                    selectCBs.remove(j);
                    try {
                        Array_of_Update_Query.remove(j);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

};

check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(Check_Boxes_Listener);
```

here is a sample on the method that is used in my running project may be its help you

Comment: can you any body provide me code solution.

Comment: chane the method according to your desire and simply call them on check change listener

Comment: whitch type of this variable selectCBs.add(Index); @Hasnain Ali

Comment: This is an array list that i use in my code you want donot need this array list you need to modify this method according to your desire