# how to get value of first column in a dynamically generated table whose checkbox is checked?

Tags: android, checkbox

I am creating an application which displays data from the server in form of table. I am also generating checkbox at the beginning of the table.

My question, how shall i get the data of the particular column(especially the first column) from the table whose checkbox is checked.

In the screenshot, i need value of product_code only, is it possible to get it's value??
Also, once i get the value of product_code, i am going to send it back to the server and store it in another database.

My code is not proper right now as i am using threads for networking but i am going to change it to asynctask soon.

Sorry for my bad english

```
public class Availability extends Activity  {

    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TextView tv;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
   HttpClient httpclient;
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    Users_availability q = new  Users_availability();
    Button book;
    CheckBox chk;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_availability);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        book=(Button)findViewById(R.id.book);

        final GetDatafromDB_Availability getdb = new GetDatafromDB_Availability();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users_availability> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();



        book.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                   Addtocart();


            }
        });
    }




    public ArrayList<Users_availability> parseJSON(String result) {
        ArrayList<Users_availability> users = new ArrayList<Users_availability>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users_availability user = new Users_availability();
                user.setId(json_data.getInt("id"));
                user.setProduct_code(json_data.getString("product_code"));
                user.setShapes(json_data.getString("shaps"));
                user.setPair(json_data.getString("pair"));
                user.setCarats(json_data.getString("carats"));
                user.setColor(json_data.getString("color"));
                user.setClarity(json_data.getString("clarity"));
                user.setService(json_data.getString("service"));
                user.setPolish(json_data.getString("polish"));
                user.setSymetric(json_data.getString("symetric"));
                user.setTables(json_data.getString("tables"));
                user.setMeasurements(json_data.getString("measurments"));
                user.setFlourscne(json_data.getString("flourscne"));
                user.setDescription(json_data.getString("description"));
                user.setCerticated(json_data.getString("certificated"));
                user.setCcode(json_data.getString("ccode"));
                user.setCut(json_data.getString("cut"));
                user.setTotal(json_data.getString("total"));
                user.setFile(json_data.getString("file"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return users;
    }



    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        TextView add = new TextView(this);
        add.setText("Add");
        add.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        add.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        add.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(add,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("Product code");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
         Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
       params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView shapes = new TextView(this);
        shapes.setText("Shapes");
        shapes.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        shapes.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        shapes.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(shapes,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

        TextView pair = new TextView(this);
        pair.setText("pair");
        pair.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        pair.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        pair.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(pair,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.



        TextView carats = new TextView(this);
        carats.setText("Carats");
        carats.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        carats.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        carats.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(carats,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.


        TextView color = new TextView(this);
        color.setText("Color");
        color.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        color.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        color.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(color,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.




        // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users_availability> users) {

        addHeader();

        for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

            Users_availability p = (Users_availability) i.next();

            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);


            chk = new CheckBox(this);

            // btn.setTextSize();
            //btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12);
            // btn.setTag(mLinks.get(index));
           // btn.setOnClickListener(this);
            //Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
           // params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
           //         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          //  params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
          //  params.width=400;
          //  params.height=60;
            // btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(10, 100));
           // Ll.addView(chk,params);

            tr.addView((View)chk);




            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getproduct_code());
            label.setId(p.getId());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            /** Creating Qty Button **/
            TextView place = new TextView(this);
            place.setText(p.getShapes());
            place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
          //  place.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(0, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(place,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getpair());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.


            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getCarats());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getColor());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getClarity());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            ////label.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BDB76B"));
            Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.



            // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }



    void Addtocart(){
        try{

            httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost= new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.106/test/cart.php"); // make sure the url is correct.
            //add your data
            nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------checkbox here..----------------------------------------------         
              if(chk.isChecked())
              {

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("product_code",q.getproduct_code().toString().trim()));


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            //Execute HTTP Post Request
            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("Response : " + response);

            /*
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   // tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + response);
                   // dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
*/  
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("cart")){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Availability.this, "Add to cart successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

               // startActivity(new Intent(Availability.this, LoginScreen.class));
            }else{
               showAlert();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            dialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        }
    }

    public void showAlert(){
        Availability.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Availability.this);
                builder.setTitle("Can't add to cart.");
                builder.setMessage("Problem in adding to cart. Please try again later")
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

}

[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: follow my this answer it may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22986460/i-have-a-multiple-checkbox-but-i-want-save-only-single-checkbox-value-in-activit/22988038#22988038

Answer (score 0):

i suggest dont go for check which position checked in table.instead of when you click on particular check box save that position to array and remove from array when unchecked.
And when you want to get data from checked check box just get data from all position stored in your temp Array. thats it..i think it is better and convenient way.

Comment: do you have any link to tutorial about how can i do it??

Comment: its simple logic dude.just get your checkbox checked change event and in that event save your position or remove position